# How to convert base64 data into image

Tags: angular

I have a dynamic data and i want few of the data to convert into image. Below is my data

```
{
          "categoryId": 6,
          "itemTitle": "Evol",
          "itemValue": "68",
          "itemUnit": "",
          "displayOrder": 3,
          "isActive": true,
          "isDeleted": false,
          "createdDate": "2022-09-22T22:08:34.1190159",
          "createdBy": 1,
          "patientId": 3209,
          "categoryName": "Lungs"
        },
        {
          "categoryId": 6,
          "itemTitle": "Graph1",
          "itemValue": "data:image/jpg;base64,/xyz,
          "itemUnit": "",
          "displayOrder": 3,
          "isActive": true,
          "isDeleted": false,
          "createdDate": "2022-09-22T22:08:34.1222285",
          "createdBy": 1,
          "patientId": 3209,
          "categoryName": "Lungs"
        },
```

And this is how i show in my UI
[image: Ui]

And this is the html code that i use to print this data

```
<div class="row">
                    <div *ngFor="let item of hubxReport.hubxDataItems" class="col-sm-4">
                      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width lineheight25 fontsize">  
                        <input class="fontsize" matInput autofocus placeholder={{item.itemTitle}}>{{item.itemValue}}&nbsp;{{item.itemUnit}}
                      </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
```

And this is my Model

```
export class HubxDataModel{ 
        categoryId:number;
        categoryName:string;
        displayOrder: number;
        HubxDataItems:HubxModel;
    }
    export class HubxModel{ 
        id: number;
        categoryId: number;
        itemTitle: string;
        itemUnit: string;
        isActive: boolean=true;
        itemValue: string;
        patientId: number;
        displayOrder : number;
        isDeleted: boolean;
    }
```

And this is how i call my data from API

```
getHubxReport() {
    this.clientService.getHubxReport(this.clientId).subscribe((response: ResponseModel) => {
      if (response != null && response.data != null && response.data.length > 0) {
        this.hubxReportList = response.data;
      }
    }
    );
   
  }
```

My question is Fev6,PEF,PEFT...Graph 1 and Graph 2 which is shown in the image is under itemtitle and image data is under itemvalue this are dynamic data. So whenever itemTitle prints graph 1 and graph 2 i want only their itemvalue data which is base64 data to convert into image.How can i acheive that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, as per your question, you know when to show the image, you can use the HTML [img](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) tag and together with help from [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer), to display image when `itemTitle` is in `['Graph 1', 'Graph 2']`.

html file -

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="item.itemTitle">
  <img
    *ngSwitchCase="
      ['Graph 1', 'Graph 2'].includes(item.itemTitle)
        ? item.itemTitle
        : !item.itemTitle
    "
    [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(item.itemValue)"
    [alt]="item.itemTitle"
  />
  <span *ngSwitchDefault>{{ item.itemValue }}</span>
</ng-container>
```

ts file -

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...

export class MyComponent {
    ...
    constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {...}
    ...
}
```

StackBlitz link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mfzhqq

Comment: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl. i have this error

Comment: and it is not converting into image

Comment: you need to add `MatInputModule` in your imports array of the module. Refer to the stack-blitz link shared in the answer.

Comment: i have updated the same code according to the stackblitz. But it is not converting into image